# Display arraylist in select box part of form

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on a simple workout tracker using Java Spring. I'm trying to create my exercise form which allows users to input exercise name/weight/reps and select the (previously created) workout they wish to add to. I've looked at many threads discussing similar issues and nothing has worked for me.

Here is the method in my WorkoutController:

```
@PostMapping("/workout/createExercise")
public String createExercise(@ModelAttribute Exercise exercise,
                             Model model) {
    Collection<Workout> workouts = workoutService.getWorkouts();
    model.addAttribute("workouts", workouts);
    workoutService.saveExercise(exercise);
    return "createExercise";
}
```

This is the form:

```
<options action="#" th:action="@{/exercise/createExercise}" th:object="${exercise}" method="post">
            Exercise name:<br>
            <input type="text" class="formInput" name="exercise-name" size="50"
                   th:field="*{exerciseName}"><br>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            Weight:<br>
            <input type="text" class="formInput" name="weight" size="50"
                   th:field="*{weight}"><br>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            Reps:<br>
            <input type="text" class="formInput" name="reps" size="50"
                   th:field="*{reps}"><br>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            Workout:<br>
            <select name="workout" class="exerciseForm" name="workout">
                <option>--</option>
                <option items="${workouts}" itemLabel="workoutName"
                       itemValue="workoutID"></option>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" class="input-box">
        </form>
```

I've tried many variations. Sometimes it does render the page but doesn't display anything when I click the dropdown box, other times, it will display the following error:

```
18-11-07 12:32:47 ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - 
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-10] Exception processing 
 template "createExercise": An error happened during 
 template parsing (template: "class path resource 
 [templates/createExercise.html]" - line 57, col 61)
 org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error 
 happened during template parsing (template: "class path 
 resource [templates/createExercise.html]" - line 57, col 61)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:239)
at
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Do you have looked at the documentation https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html 7.5 Dropdown/List selectors / It seems different in your example. Anyway you need to declare thymeleaf which property of a Workout object should be displayed in the options.

Comment: Yep. Looking at the error more closely now, it seems that it is more of a problem with my Workout being routed as a ModelAttribute.